# Java Flight Recoder cmd args to enable collection of object statistics

Tags: java, jvm, jvm-arguments, jvm-hotspot, jmc

I am using this list of command line arguments to the jvm

`-XX:+UnlockCommercialFeatures -XX:+FlightRecorder -XX:StartFlightRecording=delay=2m,duration=30m,filename=member.jfr,settings=profile`

to start a flight recording.

however when I open the .jfr recording.  I see the object statistics tab
of the memory view,  is unpopulated

also the exceptions tab is unpopulated.

how to enable the collection of object statics via the command line options.

this is not a production system, so I an not bothered about the extra overhead

I am interested in as much detail as possible.  so what are the best command line settings to use.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

> how to enable the collection of object statics via the command line
> options.

It's not possible to set it on command line directly in JDK 7/8. Use the template manager available in JMC, Windows -> Template Manager. Export a JFC-file and use with: settings=path-to-configuration-file.

In JDK 17, you can enable object statistics on command line:

```
$ java -XX:StartFlightRecording:jdk.ObjectCount#enabled=true ...
```